# JSON to Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I've been trying to append JSON data from a webserver into a tableviewcontroller. This is my current code.

The NSlog of _datalist prints the JSON, but the other methods for actually putting the data in cells, does not.. The code looks correct, and since the _datalist NSarray actually gets the data, I'm not sure how to handle this.. Which is why I need your help and advice.

As for what I've figured out, the method where the cells are initialized with the JSON data, can't either fetch it, or use it. My clue was that I need to encode the incoming data?

```
#import "TopUsersViewController.h"

@interface TopUsersViewController ()
@property  NSArray* dataList;
@end

@implementation TopUsersViewController




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self readDataFromFile];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


-(void)readDataFromFile
{


    NSString *urlAsString = @"http://myURL.com/json.json";

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlAsString];
    NSLog(@"%@", urlAsString);

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

        if (error)
        {
            // no internet / can't fetch!
            NSLog(@"Failure %@",error.localizedDescription);


        }


            NSLog(@"Success!");


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"works.");

            self.dataList = (NSArray *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:nil];

            // this NSlog prints the JSON data successfully.    
            NSLog(@"oo%@ and array %@",_dataList,_array);




            });
    }];







}
```

// none of these methods are running..

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // count the initialized array from viewDidLoad
    return self.dataList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSLog(@"return the data");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    id keyValuePair = self.dataList[indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.text = keyValuePair[@"identity"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Points: %@", keyValuePair[@"points"]];
    return cell;
}


@end
```

Comment: I'll review other questions more carefully next time, thank you for pointing that out! Happy coding!

Comment: @SyedeHussaini You really need to fix the issues in your answer if you are going to point others to it.

Comment: Also, your link was for Swift. Since my current application is written in Obj-c, its non relevant. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your `tableView` by a delegate method that you want to reload your tableView when you have data in your array...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"works.");

            self.dataList = (NSArray *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:nil];

            [self.tableView reloadData];
            // this NSlog prints the JSON data successfully.    
            NSLog(@"oo%@ and array %@",_dataList,_array);




            });
```

You are reloading your tableView in viewDidLoad Method while at that point your array has no element and when the success block of your api call is executed then you need to call reloadData method.

Comment: Oh.. Well I do have that method in viewDidLoad already? Do you think this will make a difference?
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self readDataFromFile];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: Nope that will still not run those method. Because you don't know when the success block of your API call. So you must have to reload the data when your array is loaded with data so call the reloadData method below the line where you are loading array with data.

Comment: Thank you vey much for reviewing my case. It solved it! Happy iOS coding! :)